# AHS 1% alcohol boost?

Tags: kits

Austin Homebrew Supllies offers an option on all it's kits:

> **1% Alcohol Boost:**
>   Add 1% alcohol to your beer without compromising its flavor. Brewvint Alcohol Boost is 55% maltose/45% glucose, a very fermentable mix with little flavor contribution.

I'm curious about anyone's experiences with this.  Does it really not affect flavor?  Could I (theoretically) add several of these?  Any other drawbacks to them?

Answer (score 3):

I've used it a couple of times. The alcohol boost is completely fermentable. Which means that it won't leave any sweetness behind. You could theoretically add several, but adding that much will create a lot of hot alcohols that will take a long time (6 months +) to mellow in the bottle.

But in a single dose it does not really change the taste of your beer.

Answer (score 1):

I've added this to a couple of the recipes I ordered from AHB before I switched to all-grain. I never noticed any off flavors, but I've stopped using it just because I'm fine with the ABV of the particular styles I'm brewing.